# Transferring Search Box From Old Page to New Design (From Scratch)

Tags: html, css, search-engine, xls, xlsm

I am a computer science major and relatively experienced front-end developer (HTML, CSS, Javascript, as well as some development history with PHP, Java, Ruby and Linux Command Line).

Recently I signed on with a team that is doing some webpage redesign for a product-sales company. I have been assigned to take the client's pdf templates and turn them in to working HTML/CSS files that they can implement to their website when they so please. I have got every part of the assignments complete, EXCEPT for the search box found on the header of each page.

My issue is that I need to implement the same search box from their old header design in to the new one. I found a great example that is almost exactly the same as what I am dealing with at this website (http://shop.manorfinewares.com/intro.html). [It is the search bar in the upper right]

I am unsure as to the correct process to take a search bar (such as this one) and transfer it to my new layout that I have coded for them while making sure to maintain all of its functionality when I hand them the finished product. [For sake of argument lets just say it is the EXACT same search bar as the one listed at the site linked to above]

I cannot express how grateful I am to anybody who can help out. Not quite sure what I can offer in return, but if you can think of anything, I will be sure to oblige. Any tips are greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is any other information that you may need to better assist :) Hope this message is read in good spirits and that all is well (Sorry for the length of this btw, it's my first time posting)

Comment: <div id="header">
  <div id="headerContainer">
   <div class="headerUtilityContainer">
    <img src="images/manorSocialButtons.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="headerLogoContainer">
    <img src="images/homePageLogo.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="searchContainer">
   LOGIN / REGISTER  CART (0)
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of such lengthy post, you could have posted two images, one of what you currently have and one what do you want to achieve. It's very unclear atm.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification as this was my first post to stack overflow. I will add the html and css for the header of the page that I would like to transfer the search box from. You will notice that the design is indeed for the manorfinewares website listed in the op. Any ideas which elements I will need to transfer to the new website project in order to successfully copy the search bar (and its functionality) used on their old webpage (link listed in op)?

Comment: I shortened, added relevant code, and clarified in this post. I apologize for the poor form before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823391/transfer-search-box-from-old-website-to-new-website