# Transfer Search Box From Old Website to New Website

Tags: html, css, search-engine, xlsx, vs-web-site-project

I am working for this company that has hired me to turn a new home page design of theirs into html and css. In the design they gave me there is a search box in the header that they would like to be same as the one on their current webpage (http://shop.manorfinewares.com/intro.html). I am unsure how to navigate their current page's source code in order to successfully transfer the search box to the new page I am designing for them. Here is the header code that I have so far...

CSS:

```
    #header{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        height:107px;
        min-width:600px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #86beca;

 }
#headerContainer{
                 position:relative;
                 width:100%;
                 margin:0 auto;
                 top:0;
                 height:107px;
                 max-width:1280px;
                 min-width:600px;
                 border-bottom: 1px dotted #86beca;
 }
.headerUtilityContainer{
           float:left;
           padding-top:4px;
           margin-left:8%;
           width:22%;
           height:103px;          
           }
.headerUtilityContainer img{
           float:left;
           margin-top:2px;
           width:40%;
           height:9px;
           }

.headerLogoContainer{
           float:left;
           margin:0px;
           width:40%;
           height:107px; 
           }

.headerLogoContainer img {
               display:block;
               margin-top:30px;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               width: 55%;
               max-width:250px;
               height: 57%;
               }        

.searchContainer{
        float:left;
        text-align:right;
        font-size:70%;
        padding-top:4px;
        margin-right:8%;
        width:22%;
        height:103px; 
        }

.headerBorderDiv{
                 float:left;
                 width:100%;
                 margin:0 auto;
                 padding:0px;
                 height:2px;
                 border-bottom: 1px dotted #86beca;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="headerContainer">
         <div class="headerUtilityContainer">
          <img src="images/manorSocialButtons.png" />
         </div>
         <div class="headerLogoContainer">
          <img src="images/homePageLogo.png"/>
         </div>
         <div class="searchContainer">
         LOGIN / REGISTER  CART (0)
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

ANY advice will be very helpful as I am not sure where to start. I have never worked with XLS search bars in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still unclear as to what exactly you want, a right floated search bar with clear icon on input? I have created this fiddle for you, it replicates the behaviour of site you mentioned.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/DP22Y/
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="utility">Utility</div><!-- 
--><div id="logo">Logo</div><!-- 
--><div id="search">LOGIN / REGISTER | CART (0)
        <span class="clearable">
            <input class="data_field" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
            <span class="icon_clear">x</span>
        </span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    margin:0 auto; 
    height:100px;
    width:80%;
}

#utility, #logo, #search{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#000;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
#utility{
    background:#f1f1f1; 
    width:33.3%;
    padding:10px;
} 
#logo{
    background:#e0e0e0; 
    width:33.3%;
    padding:10px; 
}
#search{
    background:#e9e9e9; 
    width:33.3%;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:right
}

#search > #data_field{
    margin:10px 0 10px;
    padding:5px;
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}

span.icon_clear{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:0px;    
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font: bold 1em sans-serif;
    color:#38468F;  
}
span.icon_clear:hover{
    color:#f52;
}
.clearable{
    position:relative;
}
.data_field{
    padding-right:17px; /* add space for the 'x' icon*/
    width:100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('propertychange keyup input paste', 'input.data_field', function(){
    var io = $(this).val().length ? 1 : 0 ;
    $(this).next('.icon_clear').stop().fadeTo(300,io);
}).on('click', '.icon_clear', function() {
    $(this).delay(300).fadeTo(300,0).prev('input').val('');
});
```

As far as the functionality is concerned, that is a different question altogether. That depends on what language you are using, do you want to make the results appear on page reload or without that using ajax, whats the db scheme etc. But the basic search would be something like this

1. Wrap search field with a form
2. Set an action and method for the form
3. Action will be the page the search results will be shown on

Comment: This was extremely helpful already Sarmad. Thank you very much for your help and for continuing to stick with me. <p>What I was hoping was that there is a way to read their home page's source code so that when I hand them the code of their newly designed page the search box will search the same as it did on their original page (ie. will search the same form and lead to the new page etc.) Is it possible for me to find how they implemented the 3 actions listed by you at the bottom of your comment from their original code?</p>

Comment: You can always inspect element, most modern browsers allow that, I use Chrome for inspecting an element, just right click on the search box and click on inspect element, it'll select the element and show the css classes and individual styles applied to it.

Comment: Oh absolutely. I was trying to figure out which of those elements were necessary to the functionality of the search box. As well as which files I needed to link to the page. It seems to be an "xls search box" which I assume means that it uses some sort of excel spreadsheet and a string search to produce results. I figure there must be some xls sheet i must import so that the box knows what to search. Does this seem correct at all to you?

Comment: LOL I highly doubt that. XLS is just an ID and a class to be used with JS and CSS. For your site, all you need to do is wrap text field around a form and give that form some action and method, I have already showed you the styling for text field and cancel button when you type in the field.